# Atiyah-McDonald, Proposition 5.6 i)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was reading *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* in order to find some answers to an exercise and I came across this proposition.

> ***Proposition 5.6.***
> Let $A \subseteq B$ be rings, $B$ integral over $A$.
>
> i) If $\mathfrak{b}$ is an ideal of $B$ and $\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{b}^c = A \cap \mathfrak{b}$, then $B/\mathfrak{b}$ is integral over $A/\mathfrak{a}$.
>
> ii) If $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$, then $S^{-1} B$ is integral over $S^{-1} A$.
>
> *Proof.*
> i) If $x \in B$ we have, say, $x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + \dotsb + a_n = 0$, with $a_i \in A$. Reduce this equation $\bmod \mathfrak{b}$.

My question is how do you get the coefficient of the polynomial to be in $A/\mathfrak{a}$ when you reduce the equation modulo $\mathfrak{b}$.

Comment: Because $\mathfrak{a}=A\cap\mathfrak{b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (first? second? third?) isomorphism theorem says that the composition $A\stackrel\iota\hookrightarrow B\stackrel{\pi_{\mathfrak b}}\to B/\mathfrak b$ induces a monomorphism of quotient spaces $A/\mathfrak b^c\stackrel{\iota'}\hookrightarrow B/\mathfrak b$. The map $\iota'$ is the only homomorphism such that $\iota'\circ\pi_{\mathfrak b^c}=\pi_{\mathfrak b}\circ \iota$. In this sense, $A/\mathfrak b^c$ is canonically a subring of $B/\mathfrak b$.

Comment: I think it's the second, thank you :)